# 403 forbidden only when use Mono/Flux on a endpoint- Spring Security 6 - Spring Boot 3 - JWT -

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, spring-webflux, reactive-programming

I need to understand why my different endpoints of my controllers do not work or allow them to work reactively using Mono or Flux, if I do not use Mono or Flux simply all the authentication and JWT process works correctly, but when trying to work with MONO it simply always returns 403 Forbidden

FOR EXAMPLE:
This give me 403 Forbidden

```
@GetMapping("/user/findByEmail/{email}")
    public Mono<ResponseEntity<UserDTO>> getUserByEmail(@PathVariable String email) {
        var auth =  SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        return Mono.just(ResponseEntity.ok(userMapper.createUserDTO(userService.findByEmail(email).block())));
    }
```

But this just works perfectly (Same code without Mono)

```
@GetMapping("/user/findByEmail/{email}")
    public ResponseEntity<UserDTO> getUserByEmail(@PathVariable String email) {
        var auth =  SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        return ResponseEntity.ok(userMapper.createUserDTO(userService.findByEmail(email).block()));
    }
```

**WebSecurityConfig.java**

```
package com.feder.App.Config;

import com.feder.App.Filter.JwtRequestFilter;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.Customizer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig {
    @Autowired
    private JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter;
    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain web(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable() // (2)
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
                        .requestMatchers("/api/public/**").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/api/user/**").hasRole("USER")
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .cors(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .sessionManagement((session) -> session
                        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                );
        return http.build();
    }
  /* (1) By default, Spring Security form login/http basic auth are enabled.
  However, as soon as any servlet-based configuration is provided,
  form based login or/and http basic auth must be explicitly provided.

  * (2) If our stateless API uses token-based authentication, such as JWT,
    we don't need CSRF protection
  */

    @Bean
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }


    @Bean
    AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration
                                                        authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
        return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }
}
```

**JwtUtilService.java**

```
package com.feder.App.Service.Security;

import io.jsonwebtoken.Claims;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;
import io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureAlgorithm;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@Service
public class JwtUtilService {
    // LLAVE_MUY_SECRETA => [Base64] => TExBVkVfTVVZX1NFQ1JFVEE=
    private static final String JWT_SECRET_KEY = "SomeLongSecret";

    public static final long JWT_TOKEN_VALIDITY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * (long) 8; // 8 Horas

    public String extractUsername(String token) {
        return extractClaim(token, Claims::getSubject);
    }

    public Date extractExpiration(String token) {
        return extractClaim(token, Claims::getExpiration);
    }

    public <T> T extractClaim(String token, Function<Claims, T> claimsResolver) {
        return claimsResolver.apply(extractAllClaims(token));
    }

    private Claims extractAllClaims(String token) {
        return Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(JWT_SECRET_KEY).parseClaimsJws(token).getBody();
    }

    private Boolean isTokenExpired(String token) {
        return extractExpiration(token).before(new Date());
    }

    public String generateToken(UserDetails userDetails) {
        Map<String, Object> claims = new HashMap<>();
        // Agregando informacion adicional como "claim"
        var rol = userDetails.getAuthorities().stream().collect(Collectors.toList()).get(0);
        claims.put("rol", rol);
        return createToken(claims, userDetails.getUsername());
    }

    private String createToken(Map<String, Object> claims, String subject) {

        return Jwts
                .builder()
                .setClaims(claims)
                .setSubject(subject)
                .setIssuedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + JWT_TOKEN_VALIDITY))
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, JWT_SECRET_KEY)
                .compact();
    }

    public boolean validateToken(String token, UserDetails userDetails) {
        final String username = extractUsername(token);
        return (username.equals(userDetails.getUsername()) && !isTokenExpired(token));
    }
}
```

**UserDetailServiceImpl.java**

```
package com.feder.App.Service.Security;

import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.*;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

@Service
public class UserDetailServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {
    public record Usuario(String username, String password, Set<String> roles) {};

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        var authUser = getById(username);

        if (authUser == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(username);
        }
        return User
                .withUsername(username)
                .password(authUser.password())
                .roles(authUser.roles().toArray(new String[0]))
                .build();
    }
    
    public static Usuario getById(String username) {
        // "secreto" => [BCrypt] => "Something"
        var password = "Something"

        Usuario juan = new Usuario(
                "jcabelloc",
                password,
                Set.of("USER")
        );

        Usuario maria = new Usuario(
                "mlopez",
                password,
                Set.of("ADMIN")
        );
        var usuarios = List.of(juan, maria);

        return usuarios
                .stream()
                .filter(e -> e.username().equals(username))
                .findFirst()
                .orElse(null);
    }
}
```

**JwtRequestFilter.java**

```
package com.feder.App.Filter;

import com.feder.App.Service.Security.JwtUtilService;
import jakarta.servlet.FilterChain;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetailsSource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

import java.io.IOException;

@Component
public class JwtRequestFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtUtilService jwtUtilService;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        final String authorizationHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");

        String username = null;
        String jwt = null;

        if (authorizationHeader != null && authorizationHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            jwt = authorizationHeader.substring(7);
            username = jwtUtilService.extractUsername(jwt);
        }


        if (username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {

            UserDetails userDetails = this.userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);

            if (jwtUtilService.validateToken(jwt, userDetails)) {

                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                authenticationToken.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticationToken);
            }
        }
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

}
```

**MODEL: AuthenticationReq.java**

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class AuthenticationReq implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String usuario;

    private String clave;

    public AuthenticationReq(String usuario, String clave) {
        this.usuario = usuario;
        this.clave = clave;
    }

    public String getUsuario() {
        return usuario;
    }

    public void setUsuario(String username) {
        this.usuario = usuario;
    }

    public String getClave() {
        return clave;
    }

    public void setClave(String clave) {
        this.clave = clave;
    }
}
```

**MODEL: Tokeninfo**

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public record TokenInfo(String jwtToken) {}
```

I have tried to modify the UserDetailServiceImpl class so that instead of implementing it from UserDetailService it does so from ReactiveUserDetailsService, but I have not been able to make it work.

My goal is to build endpoints that work reactively, being able to use Mono or Flux

Comment: your entire "filter" should be deleted, and instead you should actually spend some time reaading the spring security documentation before asking here. Spring has built in handling of JWTs in the framework since 2017 in accordance with the reasource server specification of the oauth2 rfc.

Comment: Afaik , JWT authentication without OAuth2 is not supported  by spring security out of the box. So it is very reasonable  for people to implement their filter if they just want to do JWT authentication without OAuth2

Answer (score 0):

It is the expected  behaviour as reactive application has its own way to configure the security which is totally different from the servlet application. For example, you have to configure

- `SecurityWebFilterChain` rather than `SecurityFilterChain`
- `ReactiveAuthenticationManager` rather than `AuthenticationManager`
- `JwtRequestFilter` should be in `WebFilter` rather than `OncePerRequestFilter`
- etc.

Basically you have to update the configuration of all parts to the related reactive version.

Refer to the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/reactive/index.html) for details.